# How can I find buttons inside a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to find the `$form` object on my page:

```
var $form = $modal.find('#modal-form');
```

Now I need to select the buttons. How can I select each button inside the form, so I can apply a filter to it like this?

```
$('button').filter(function () {  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use another `find`, within the context of `$form`:

```
var $form = $modal.find('#modal-form');
var $buttons = $form.find("button");
```

Or alternatively, use [`$(selector [, context ])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
var $buttons = $("button", $form);
```

Both will find *all* `button` descendants of the given form.

Comment: If you use `:button` you also get button inputs of type reset or submit.

Comment: @elclanrs Although useful, `:button` is non-standard and cannot take advantage of native DOM methods - see http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Comment: Doubt it would make much of a difference unless you have 1000+ buttons or something crazy

Comment: Also, although not specifically mentioned in the ticket, it's likely to have been deprecated and could be removed - see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
$("#modal-form button").each(function(btn){
   console.log(btn);//Logs each button in the form to your console 
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#modal-form button`? Find buttons within #modal-form?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.find()` function on the form element:

```
var $form = $modal.find('#modal-form');
var button = $form.find('button');
```

Comment: But I have more than one button. Will that find them all? Also how could I apply the filter to the variable called button?

Comment: Yes, that will find them all. If you had a combination of <button> tags and <input type="button" />, you could do: `var buttons = $form.find('button, input[type="button"]');` to get them all. What are you trying to do by using the filter?